# Heroku shows 'Procfile declares types -> (none)' but I am declaring a web process

Tags: django, heroku, deployment, procfile, application-error

I have tried each and everything... Renamed the Procfile, moved it to the root directory, etc. Wee the images below.

This is the error showing on my webapp page:

[image]

This is showing on my dashboard as Heroku has not recognized my Procfile:

[image]

This is the directory in which Procfile is there:

[image]

I see this when I deploy:

```
Procfile declares types -> (none)
```

This is the content of my Procfile:

[image]

**Please Help me out**

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you see the third column in your Windows screenshot, where it says "Text Document" for your `Procfile`? That file is actually called *`Procfile.txt`*, not `Procfile`.

[image: Windows Explorer]

Windows hides file extensions for known file types by default, but [you can turn them on](https://superuser.com/q/494312) in the "View" tab. After doing that, rename your file to *actually* be called `Procfile`, commit, and then redeploy.

Alternatively, if you're using Git bash, you can do this on the command line:

```
git mv Procfile.txt Procfile
git commit -m "Fix Procfile name"
```